# BeanDefinition class removed in Spring 4?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I am trying out the new Spring 4 release, and I found out that the `BeanDefinition` interface has been removed, if so what is the replacement class we should use in a scenario where we define a scope for a bean ?

Prior to Spring release of 4 you could do this.

```
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class MyBean{
  ...
}
```

EDIT

As of Spring 4, can't you specify the spring bean scope in the @Scope Annotation, the only option given is to add a string and then the ProxyMode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not removed. You can find it in the  `org.springframework.beans.factory.config` package
which can in turn is in `spring-beans.jar` which can be found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.5.RELEASE)

As @John points out, the corresponding Javadoc can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html)

Comment: The corresponding javadoc can also be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html).

Comment: yes i meant BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, sorry for the typo,edited the question.

Comment: @mushtaq I removed the corresponding comment from my answer

Comment: As of Spring 4, can't you specify the spring bean scope in the @Scope Annotation, the only option given is to add a string and then the ProxyMode.